# Change tone frequency of synthesized sound in AudioKit

Tags: audiokit

I am using the STKAudiokitdemo playground to change the beat of a metronome in realtime. The metronome sound is synthesized using the Stanforf Synthesis Toolkit. This is all plain vanilla of the STKAudiokitdemo playground. Now I want to change the tone frequency of the synthesized sound in addition to the beat in real time. Is this possible?

````
class ShakerConductor: ObservableObject, HasAudioEngine {
        let engine = AudioEngine()
        let shaker = Shaker()
        var callbackInst = CallbackInstrument()
        let reverb: Reverb
        let mixer = Mixer()
        var sequencer = Sequencer()

        @Published var data = ShakerMetronomeData() {
            didSet {
                data.isPlaying ? sequencer.play() : sequencer.stop()
                sequencer.tempo = data.tempo
                updateSequences()
            }
        }
        
        @State private var response: String = ""
    
        func updateSequences() {
            var track = sequencer.tracks.first!
    
            track.length = Double(data.timeSignatureTop)
    
            track.clear()
            track.sequence.add(noteNumber: data.downbeatNoteNumber, position: 0.0, duration: 0.1)
            let vel = MIDIVelocity(Int(data.beatNoteVelocity))
            for beat in 1 ..< data.timeSignatureTop {
                track.sequence.add(noteNumber: data.beatNoteNumber, velocity: vel, position: Double(beat), duration: 0.1)
            }
    
            track = sequencer.tracks[1]
            track.length = Double(data.timeSignatureTop)
            track.clear()
            for beat in 0 ..< data.timeSignatureTop {
                track.sequence.add(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber(beat), position: Double(beat), duration: 0.1)
            }
        } ```
````

Comment: What do you mean be "in real time"? What did you try? The frequency is defined by the note number, so everywhere you see "noteNumber" you may change the pitch of the played sound

Comment: It is my understanding that the Shakers class  in the STK plays a different "instrument" for every MIDINoteNumber. For example: Sand Paper = 6, Coke Can = 7, Sticks = 8. In my case I play MIDINoteNumer(7) and want to change the pitch of that sound.

Comment: You can try feeding the Shaker output to a TimePitch module and then edit the Pitch.